# How to sort semantic versions in bash?

Tags: bash, sorting, version, semantic-versioning

I would like to sort semantic versions ([semver.org](http://semver.org))

```
v1.4.0
v1.4.0-alpha
v1.4.0-alpha1
v1.4.0-patch
v1.4.0-patch9
v1.4.0-patch10
v1.4.0-patch2
v1.5.0
v1.5.0-alpha
v1.5.0-alpha1
v1.5.0-alpha2
v1.5.0-patch
v1.5.0-patch1
```

in proper way. For instance, as [`version_compare()` does in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) (it doesn't directly, but can be used for that).

Of course, `sort -V|--version-sort` doesn't work here.

```
$ echo 1.0 1.0-alpha | tr ' ' "\n" | sort --version-sort
1.0
1.0-alpha
```

Is there some exist approach?

**P.S.**

In common sense, it should follow this schema:

```
1.0.0-alpha 
  < 1.0.0-alpha.1 
    < 1.0.0-alpha.beta 
      < 1.0.0-beta
        < 1.0.0-beta.2
          < 1.0.0-beta.11
           < 1.0.0-rc.1 < 1.0.0
             < 1.0.0-patch < 1.0.0-patch.1.
```

**P.P.S.**

Semver 2.0 doesn't support patches, but it's needed.

Comment: The "-patch" requirement makes this incompatible with semver, so you should not call this semver.

On the other hand, semver doesn't support third party patches, it's made only for official releases (in that case of a patch, the source developer should add 1 to the number in the PATCH section). If you're really pushing it, maybe it can be done with +metadata after the end of the version.

Comment: Yeah, it's true. It doesn't support "patch" type versions. About meta data - package managers DO NOT consider meta data. They cutting it off. I'm talking about composer, exactly. So, there are might be issues.

Comment: it means, it will make unexpected result, you try to get 1.0.0 version there are two version, like: 1.0.0 and 1.0.0+super-patch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Custom script in bash**

I implemented [my own solution](https://gist.github.com/andkirby/54204328823febad9d34422427b1937b)

The code a bit ugly, but it works.

*Installation*

```
$ curl -Ls https://gist.github.com/andkirby/0046df5cad44f86b670a102b7c8b7ba7/raw/version_sort_install.sh | bash
Semantic version sort: /usr/bin/semversort

$ semversort 1.0 1.0-rc 1.0-patch 1.0-alpha
1.0-alpha
1.0-rc
1.0
1.0-patch
```

**2. Using [semver in node](https://github.com/npm/node-semver)**

NOTE: All versions must follow the particular schema and it DOESN'T support "patch".

https://github.com/npm/node-semver/blob/master/README.md

```
$ npm install --global semver
C:\Users\u.user\.node\semver -> C:\Users\u.user\.node\node_modules\semver\bin\semver
semver@5.3.0 C:\Users\u.user\.node\node_modules\semver

$ ~/.node/semver 1.2.3 1.3.6-patch 1.3.6-beta 1.3.6 1.3.6-alpha 1.0.4
1.0.4
1.2.3
1.3.6-alpha
1.3.6-beta
1.3.6-patch
1.3.6
```

**3. Using PHP and version_compare() in console**

Also, the PHP native `version_compare()` (with using PHP of course :)) [here](https://gist.github.com/andkirby/0046df5cad44f86b670a102b7c8b7ba7).

Answer (score 38):

Well, we could trick `sort -V` by adding a dummy character at the end of the string for lines that do not contain a hyphen:

```
$ echo "$versions" | sed '/-/!{s/$/_/}' | sort -V | sed 's/_$//'
v1.4.0-alpha
v1.4.0-alpha1
v1.4.0-patch
v1.4.0-patch2
v1.4.0-patch9
v1.4.0-patch10
v1.4.0
v1.5.0-alpha
v1.5.0-alpha1
v1.5.0-alpha2
v1.5.0-patch
v1.5.0-patch1
v1.5.0
```

Underscore lexically sorts *after* hyphen. That's the trick.

---

Handling patches can use he same strategy: replace the hyphen with an underscore, and restore it after sorting

```bash
cat << VERSIONS | sed '/-/!{s/$/_/;}; s/-patch/_patch/' | sort -V | sed 's/_$//; s/_patch/-patch/'
v1.4.0-alpha
v1.4.0-alpha1
v1.4.0-beta
v1.4.0-patch
v1.4.0-patch2
v1.4.0-patch9
v1.4.0-patch10
v1.4.0-rc1
v1.4.0
v1.5.0-alpha
v1.5.0-alpha2
v1.5.0-alpha1
v1.5.0-beta
v1.5.0-patch
v1.5.0-patch1
v1.5.0-beta2
v1.5.0
VERSIONS
```

outputs

```
v1.4.0-alpha
v1.4.0-alpha1
v1.4.0-beta
v1.4.0-rc1
v1.4.0
v1.4.0-patch
v1.4.0-patch2
v1.4.0-patch9
v1.4.0-patch10
v1.5.0-alpha
v1.5.0-alpha1
v1.5.0-alpha2
v1.5.0-beta
v1.5.0-beta2
v1.5.0
v1.5.0-patch
v1.5.0-patch1
```

Comment: True. :) So, why you've added this? :)

Comment: Um, because you didn't show us your expected output?

Comment: Sorry, if it's unclear. So, I've considered semver, it doesn't have patches... :( If you command will sort RC and beta, it can be an answer for question without patches.

Comment: This can fail under macos, you should be using gsed

Comment: @shadowbq It will work with mac `sed` if you get rid of the optional curly braces: `sed '/-/! s/$/_/'` (I added a space for readability.)

Comment: If you're wondering why you can't simply add an `_` to every line, it's because it would mess up the order of `alpha` and `alpha1`. `alpha1_` would come before `alpha_`, which is wrong.

Comment: "sort -V" is the key.

Answer (score 28):

You can use Linux sort:

```
$ printf "1.0\n2.0\n2.12\n2.10\n1.2\n1.10" | sort -t "." -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n
1.0
1.2
1.10
2.0
2.10
2.12
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/loisaidasam/b1e6879f3deb495c22cc#gistcomment-1613531

Comment: That doesn't work if there are release candidates, for instance 2.12-rc1 would be sorted _after_ 2.12, when it should be _before_ it.

Comment: Very thanks for such sort ability. It helps to sort proper semver versioning (while I not use suffixes e.g rc, alpha). My full command for fetching largest version from git looks next `git for-each-ref --sort=creatordate --format '%(refname)' refs/tags | grep -E "^refs/tags/${PREFIX_DASH}[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$" | grep -E "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" -o | sort -t "." -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n | tail -n 1`

Comment: Thanks, this works on Snow Leopard (don't ask).

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks! If only the other guy had used python instead of bash to write the script...but anyway thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```
| sed -e 's/["\,\s]//g' \ # remove bad symbols:    1.2.3       1.2.3-123   1.2.3-patch
| sed '/-/! s/$/@999/' \ # replace releases:       1.2.3@999   1.2.3-123   1.2.3-patch
| sed 's/[\-\.]/@/g' \ # replaces separators:      1@2@3@999   1@2@3@123   1@2@3@patch
| sed 's/@patch/@9999@/' \ # replace patches:      1@2@3@999   1@2@3@123   1@2@3@9999
| sort -n -t @ -k1 -k2 -k3 -k4 \ # sort by numbers 
| sed 's/@9999@/@patch/' \  # replace back         1@2@3@999   1@2@3@123   1@2@3@patch
| sed 's/@999//' \  # replace back                 1@2@3       1@2@3@123   1@2@3@patch
| sed 's/@/./' \  # replace back                   1.2@3       1.2@3@123   1.2@3@patch
| sed 's/@/./' \  # replace back                   1.2.3       1.2.3@123   1.2.3@patch
| sed 's/@/-/'  # replace back                     1.2.3       1.2.3-123   1.2.3-patch
```

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/glpi-project/glpi/releases | jq --raw-output '.[] | .tag_name' |  sed '/-/!{s/$/_/}' | sort -V | sed 's/_$//'
```

This does not correct show versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gplv2 (native osx) tooling, the answer by @Glenn Jack doesn't work unless using gsed.

This native awk command can substitute.

```sh
| awk '{ if ($1 ~ /-/) print; else print $0"_" ; }' |sort -rV | sed 's/_$//'
```

Answer (score 0):

semantic versions sort with jq:

```bash
# test: versions from example on https://semver.org in reversed order
echo "1.0.0 1.0.0-rc.1 1.0.0-beta.11 1.0.0-beta.2 1.0.0-beta 1.0.0-alpha.beta 1.0.0-alpha.1 1.0.0-alpha "\
| while read -d" " version; do echo $version; done \
| jq -Rrn '
# read input lines as an array
[inputs]
|sort_by(
  # ignore build
  split("+")[0]
  # extract version core and pre-release as arrays of numbers and strings
  |split("-")
  |(.[0]|split(".")|map(tonumber? // .)) as $version_core
  |(.[1:]|join("-")|split(".")|map(tonumber? // .)) as $pre_release
  # sort by version core
  |$version_core,
  # pre-release versions have a lower precedence than the associated normal version
  ($pre_release|length)==0,
  # sort by pre-release
  $pre_release
)
#extract values from an array
|.[]'
1.0.0-alpha
1.0.0-alpha.1
1.0.0-alpha.beta
1.0.0-beta
1.0.0-beta.2
1.0.0-beta.11
1.0.0-rc.1
1.0.0
```